# Cannot debug in VS 2022 by attaching to Chrome 64bit

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, debugging

I upgraded Chrome 32 to 64 bit under latest Windows 10, and now my VS2022 projects cannot debug using Chrome as my browser of choice. They run fine under Firefox (latest) and even MS Edge.

I get this *cannot attach* error:

[image]

My debug profiles:

```
  "profiles": {
    "ShippingScheduler": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:8822",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:8822",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
```

I did notice that Chrome 64bit now takes over 15 seconds to even open, as a normal browser. It's also slow when attempting to run it under VS2022.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chrome Installer was running in the background and took a whopping 20-30 mins to complete, even though I could "run" Chrome as a normal browser. After a few reboots and clearing the caches, Chrome 64 bit started-up normally and I was able to attach VS processes to it.